# Average of Counts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table called totals and the data looks like:

```
ACC_ID  Data_ID  Mon      Weeks   Total_AR_Count   Total_FR_Count  Total_OP_Count
23      9        01/2011  4       172              251             194
42      9        01/2011  4       2                16              28
75      9        01/2011  4       33               316             346
75      9        07/2011  5       1                12              20
42      9        09/2011  5       25               758             25
```

I want the output to be as Average of all the counts grouped by ACC_ID and Data_ID:

```
ACC_ID   Data_ID  Avg_AR_Count  Avg_FR_Count  Avg_OP_Count
23       9        172           251           194
42       9        13.5          387           26.5
75       9        17            164           183
```

How can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description of what you want just about writes the SQL:

```
SELECT ACC_ID, Data ID, AVG(Total_AR_Count) AS Avg_AR_Count, AVG(Total_FR_Count) AS Avg_FR_Count...
  FROM table
 GROUP BY ACC_ID, Data_ID
```